# Is it possible to view all implications of a given predicate being true or false?

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

I am trying to build a machine which can answer user-given questions but I have a problem which I don't know how to resolve, it boils down to the following:

Imagine the following program:

```
friendlycat(X)  :- cat(X), friendly(X).
cat("Felix").
```

We want to know if Felix is a friendly cat, so we use friendlycat("Felix").
The problem is that we, the programmer, don't know if Felix is a friendly cat or not. Is there a way to automatically see the implications if friendly(X) would be true of false given a certain X?

For example, can we get output which looks like this?

```
Felix (friendly("Felix") = True)
False (friendly("Felix") = False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you check out [**Constraint Handling Rules** (CHR)](http://www.informatik.uni-ulm.de/pm/fileadmin/pm/home/fruehwirth/constraint-handling-rules-book.html).

This may be your best bet to quickly reason about such constraints and their implications.

For example:

```
:- use_module(library(chr)).

:- chr_constraint cat/1, friendly/1, friendlycat/1.

cat(X), friendly(X) ==> friendlycat(X).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- cat(felix), friendly(felix).
cat(felix),
friendly(felix),
friendlycat(felix).

?- cat(X), friendly(X).
cat(X),
friendly(X),
friendlycat(X).
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into this.